# Does anyone know what "discoverd" daemon is?

Tags: macos, daemon

Saw this process running in Activity Monitor.  Not sure what it does...anyone seen this before?

Tried searching for list of "normal" mac os daemons but most lists are incomplete.  Have not found any sites which listed "discoverd" as one of the standard daemons.  Is this a malware?

Comment: Is it "discoverd" or "discoverYd"? The latter is normal on Yosemite (it replaced mDNSResponder).

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/discoverd:

> DiscoverD is a collection of discovery and monitoring daemons to scan
>   and collect all information available about any active host running on
>   your network. This collection of daemons comes with an optional web
>   front-end running on a classic LAMP stack (Apache2, PHP5) to configure
>   the various options and to watch the monitoring results.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of OS X would help, but discoverd is a standard daemon. [It replaces the old MDNS responder for use with bonjour on OS X 10.10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151101/discoveryd-alternative-to-replace-mdnsresponder-argument).

There's no need to worry